# amp selector not working when opening amp-email in Gmail, the tick box section goes off completely

Tags: gmail, amp-html, amp-email

[image: How it is looking inside gmail]

[image: How it should've actually looked like]

There is something wrong with the tick box thing, using something like `<input type="checkbox">` also didn't work with the delivered email

Here is the link to playground for sample snippet
[Link to code snippet](https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Fcomponents%2Famp-selector.email&format=email&_gl=1*epz20j*_ga*YW1wLUE1dFpKaXQwaEhoNWgzSnVOWWFSUGc.&runtime=amp4email)

Test how it looks on gmail by pasting and sending using Gmail for amp playground https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/

Comment: Your "Link to code snippet" returns 404.

Comment: @SuZhang you can try this link, it points to the official doc examples, checkout the last snippet, the one with checkboxes, if you try sending that to gmail, it would lead to what is written above.

Comment: Link to snippet : https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Fcomponents%2Famp-selector.email&format=email&_gl=1*epz20j*_ga*YW1wLUE1dFpKaXQwaEhoNWgzSnVOWWFSUGc.&runtime=amp4email

Comment: That example has a few CSS rules that aren't allowed in AMP for Email (https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email-spec/amp-email-css/?format=email), most notably variables and `:before`. If you remove these, the email should render correctly.